# How to Disable Toggle Open Documents in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, netbeans-7

NetBeans (7) is very nice for letting you customize your keyboard shortcuts.

Personally, I want <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> to switch to the tab to the right and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> to switch left, but at the moment these launch the annoying Toggle Between Open Documents popup:

[image: Aforementioned annoying popup]

I have already set my keyboard shortcuts to have "next tab" using the workaround for getting the tab in there described [here](http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic50242.html), but the Toggle Open Documents behavior is not configurable from that menu and is overriding my shortcut.

[image]

:(?

*PS: No desire to switch my whole key bindings over to another profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim it cannot be done, because if it could be then someone on SO would know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Using Netbeans 7.2, I find that after configuring the shortcuts as per your screenshots briefly pressing CTRL+TAB switches to the tab to the right, and pressing CTRL+SHIFT+TAB briefly switches to the tab to the left.
The annoying popup thing only appears if you press and hold these buttons.

Comment: If you have only two tabs open, OR if the two adjacent tabs are each the most recently visited tabs, then you will witness that behavior. The pop-up comes up only after a delay, true, but the tab order is "most recently seen" even when skipping the pop-up, whereas I want it to be "next tab to right" (/ "next tab to left").

Comment: It would appear, then, that the only way to get what you want is to modify netbeans. Perhaps a strategically deleted class file from one of it's jars will disable this annoying popup?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is still impossible in Netbeans 7.3.1. The tab switcher appears to be hard-coded to Ctrl + Tab.

As a workaround, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pg Dn</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pg Up</kbd> in turn appear to be hard-coded to the next tab and previous tab actions.